# Connecting to MySql database with SSH tunneling on remote host with specific mysql host

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc, ssh

I am using [Jsch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) to connect to the remote mysql database where the ssh host is not the same as the mysql host as shown by the **Upper half** of the picture below:
[image]

Below is the code I am using for SSH Connection:

```
private static void connectSSH() throws SQLException {
    try {
        java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        jsch.setLogger(new MyLogger());
        session = jsch.getSession(sshUser, sshHost, 22);
        jsch.addIdentity(SshKeyFilepath, sshPassword);
        config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        config.put("ConnectionAttempts", "3");
        session.setConfig(config);
        session.connect();

        System.out.println("SSH Connected");

        Class.forName(driverName).newInstance();

        int assinged_port = session.setPortForwardingL(localPort, remoteHost, remotePort);

        System.out.println("localhost:" + assinged_port + " -> " + sshHost + ":" + remotePort);
        System.out.println("Port Forwarded");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and eventually connecting to the database using the code below:

```
 Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:" + localPort, dbUser, dbPassword);
```

I am able to do an SSH connection successfully but the execution is getting hung up when at the line below:

```
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:" + localPort, dbUser, dbPassword);
```

I have double checked my SSH and database credentials by connecting on commandline I am able to connect to the database using

```
mysql -h host1 -u "myusername" -p"mypasswordhere"
```

I suppose the problem might be due to the fact that on remote host the mysql host **is not** localhost but **host1** which I don't know where to specify in the jdbc url.

Comment: did you netstat on your local and the remote machine while "hung" ? might be firewall / routing issue

Comment: did on my "local" while being hung it says "ESTABLISHED" for the connection using my local port forwaded to remote machine

Comment: so tunnel seems okay. Do you have netstat for the host you tunneled into?

Comment: Did so but what to look for?

Comment: check for target-ip mysql and target-port mysql port. socket should originate from localhost (linux box) as that's where your packets leave the tunnel

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100475/discussion-between-anirudh-and-jan).

Comment: I'm not sure, but never saw a JDBC Connection String without a Database selecting, e.g. jdbc:mysql://<hostname>:<port>/<dbname>

Comment: But the DB name is option while connecting to a database

Comment: @s.meissner Thanks for your help that day i found a silly mistake in my code causing the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it was wrong way of port forwarding that was the root cause of the problem:

instead of:

```
int assinged_port = session.setPortForwardingL(localPort, remoteHost, remotePort);
```

it should have been

```
int assinged_port = session.setPortForwardingL(localPort, localSSHUrl, remotePort);
```

The connection runs fine now.

Comment: I have similar problem. Could you post entire code snippet?

Comment: Hi Anirudh. Am also facing the same issue. Can you let me know what is localSSHUrl?

Answer (score 4):

I know this is old, but the localSSHUrl is really the host that you would use when you are logged in to SSH.

In short, this is usually “localhost” when you are trying to connect to databases as a local user.

```
int assigned_port = session.setPortForwardingL(localPort, “localhost”, remotePort);
```

Many examples use remote_host to connect both to the SSH and to the database via port forwarding, but if you only have local access to the database, it will fail to connect.